# Emulating a toggle button with JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery

I have a number of elements with the same class like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="togglebutton">elem1</li>
  <li class="togglebutton">elem2</li>
  <li class="togglebutton selected">elem3</li>
  <li class="togglebutton">elem4</li>
</ul>
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</body>
</html>
```

The selected element has a different color from the other elements. When a user clicks on ANOTHER element, I want that element to have the selected class - and all other elements should no longer have the selected class. In other words, only one element can be selected at any time.

I think I have worked out the logic, but I am not sure how to implement it using jQuery.

basically my approach would be:

(When an item is selected):

1. Select all items using selector "ul > li.togglebutton"
2. remove class 'selected' from all of the items fetched in step 1
3. add class 'selected' to the current element that was clicked on.

Is this logic correct, or is there a better way of going about it?

Also, how may I implement the above logic (assuming there is no better alternative), using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul li.togglebutton").click(function() {
     $("ul li.togglebutton").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

edit: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XfN4s/